# psql: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, could not connect to server

Tags: linux, database, bash, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to a remote psql server and I get the below error:

```
psql: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP_Address", user "root", database "testdb", SSL off
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
```

PostgreSQL server log:

```
t[2020-04-15 16:42:30.634 +03] p[19813] hp[<IP_Address>(51448)] db[[unknown]] u[[unknown]] a[[unknown]] tx[0:] s[5e970f46.4d65:1] e[00000] i[] LOG:  connection received: host=<IP_Address> port=51448

t[2020-04-15 16:42:30.636 +03] p[19813] hp[<IP_Address>(51448)] db[testdb] u[root] a[[unknown]] tx[0:5/276857] s[5e970f46.4d65:2] e[28000] i[authentication] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<IP_Address>", user "root", database "testdb", SSL off
```

Psql server receives the connection but cant authenticate the user for db but root user have all privileges on testdb.

I have the following entry in my hba conf:

```
host     testdb          root          <IP_Address/32>          trust
```

I have the following lines in my bash script which connects to remote psql and insert required values.

```
database="testdb"
result=`df -h`
hostname=`hostname`
psql -h <IP_Address> -U root -d $database -c "INSERT INTO os.info VALUES ('$hostname','$result')"
```

The user root in psql hasn't got password. Script is working fine in local psql server .

Answer (score 0):

In your PSQL connection string the IP_Address need to be replace with the IP of remote server.

Are you declaring the IP_Address parameter in your bash script?
if yes then your psql connection string need to use that parameter by replacing IP_Address with $IP_Address and string will be like

```
psql -h $IP_Address -U root -d $database -c "INSERT INTO os.info VALUES ('$hostname','$result')"
```

Comment: I statically write my IP address after psql -h <IP_address>. I just want to mask them and write it this way. I dont pass a parameter that has the IP Address value to psql command. I just write remote ip address to there.

Comment: From this error "psql: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP_Address", user "root", database "testdb", SSL off" it is clear that someone the connection string still has IP_Address instead of actual IP. Will you please just try to run the below from your installation bin directory without using any scripts

./psql -h actual_ip_here_of_target_server -p 5432 -U root -d testdb

Comment: Also make sure you have IP of system from where you are accessing in pg_hba.conf of target server.e.g if your client system has ip 192.168.1.26
"host     testdb          root          192.168.1.26/32          trust"
Also restart the dbserver after adding this information.

Comment: Do make sure that target server has user root as well. Or for the sake of connectivity try with a user that is already present there on target server.